# How to sum using concurrent values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

Below is the sample data and the code that I am using.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(data.table)

   firm <- c("firm1","firm2","firm3","firm4","firm5","firm6","firm7","firm8","firm9")
   employment <- c(1,50,90,249,499,115,145,261,210)
   small <- c(1,1,1,3,4,2,2,4,3)

   smbtest <- data.frame(firm,employment,small)

   smbsummary <- smbtest %>% 
   select (employment,small) %>%
   group_by(small) %>%
   summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n())
```

The desired result is such

```
   smb     employment    worksites
    1          141           3
    2          401           5
    3          860           7
    4         1620           9
```

smb denotes small business. the values for smb follow the following schema

```
  smb1     >= 0 and <100
  smb2     >= 0 and <150
  smb3     >= 0 and <250
  smb4     >= 0 and <500
```

This is what I am getting

```
   smb     employment   worksites
    1          141          3
    2          260          2
    3          459          2 
    4          760          2
```

So the question is how would I set this up to where it does not separate out the unique elements. I want it to be cumulative. 0 to 100 being part of 1 to 150 if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just to need to add a `mutate` step at the end to get the cumulative sum (`cumsum` of the 'worksites').  By default, the last group is dropped (as there is only one group, it will be dropped automatically, but specifying `.groups` is better)

```
library(dplyr)
smbtest %>% 
  select(employment,small) %>%
  group_by(small) %>%
  summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(), 
         .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(worksites = cumsum(worksites))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  small employment worksites
#* <dbl>      <dbl>     <int>
#1     1        141         3
#2     2        260         5
#3     3        459         7
#4     4        760         9
```

---

If we need multiple columns to be cumulative summed, then use `across`

```
smbtest %>% 
  select(employment,small) %>%
  group_by(small) %>%
  summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(), 
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(across(c(employment, worksites), cumsum))
```

---

Or a similar option in `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
slt(smbtest, employment, small) %>%
    fgroup_by(small) %>%
    fsummarise(worksites = fNobs(employment), 
              employment = fsum(employment)) %>%    
    ftransformv(-1, cumsum)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  small worksites employment
#  <dbl>     <int>      <dbl>
#1     1         3        141
#2     2         5        401
#3     3         7        860
#4     4         9       1620
```

#### data

```
smbtest <- tibble(firm, employment, small)
```

Comment: how would I do what you did to worksites to the employment?

Comment: @TimWilcox Sorry, I was away.  The update should work

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small modification to @akrun's answer that gets the employment cumulative sums you were looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
smbtest %>% 
  select(employment,small) %>%
  group_by(small) %>%
  summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(), 
            .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(employment = cumsum(employment),
         worksites = cumsum(worksites))

#   small employment worksites
#   <dbl>      <dbl>     <int>
# 1     1        141         3
# 2     2        401         5
# 3     3        860         7
# 4     4       1620         9
```